# What does "酒" mean in "扮家家酒"？

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know “酒” usually means wine in Chinese, but what does "酒" mean in "扮家家酒"？ I could not see how the word for wine is referring to in this children's game.

Comment: 喝喜酒 =  赴喜宴. The 扮家家酒 game is to pretend to have a lively family gathering. 酒 should refer to a 酒宴 (banquet) -->喜宴 -->聚會

Answer (score 2, accepted):

喝喜酒 = 赴喜宴

設/擺酒席 = 設宴

The 扮家家酒 game is to pretend to have a lively family gathering.

酒 should refer to a 酒席 (banquet) -->喜宴 -->聚會

> [扮家家酒](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%89%AE%E5%AE%B6%E5%AE%B6%E9%85%92)
> Also called 过家家

> 小朋友一起各自扮演不同的角色，往往是模仿家里成员，做一些小孩子们眼中大人应做的事情。
> Children play different roles together, often imitating family members and doing things that children think adults should do.

Banquet, party, socializing, and drink are adult things.